# jQuery ajax get html content and pass parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to move the html contents in append() of this code below to a new .html file then use ajax to get those contents to append back to my file

This is my old code

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#table_body').append('<tr><td>'+ data[i].variable1 +'</td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callFunctionA(\''+data[i].variable2+'\');"></a></td></tr>');
}
```

And I want to change my code to be like this

.js file:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     $.ajax({
          url: "table_body.html",
          success  : function(result){ $('#table_body').append(result) }
```

.html file:

```
<tr>
<td>data[i].variable1</td>
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callFunctionA(\''+data[i].variable2+'\');"></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

But how can I pass dynamic value to data[i].variable1 and data[i].variable2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Just came up with a different solution than the original. Assuming you don't want to GET parameter on the other side. It's all js now.

```
<script>
    var data = [{variable1:'row1 td1',variable2:'row1 td2'},{variable1:'row2 td1',variable2:'row2 td2'}];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "table_body.html",
            indexVal: i,
            success: function(result,i){
                id = this.indexVal;
                res = result.replace("__data1__", data[id].variable1).replace("__data2__", data[id].variable2);
                $('#table_body').append(res);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And in the `table_body.html` file

```
<tr>
    <td>__data1__</td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callFunctionA('__data2__');">click me</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```